# How can I show that all the solutions of the equation $T(v)=\omega_0$ are of the form of $v=v_0+u$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$T:V \to W$ is the linear transformation of the vector spaces $V$ and $W$.
Let's take $v_0$ which is an element of $V$ as $T(v_0)=\omega_0$.

How can I show that all the solutions of the equation $T(v)=\omega_0$ are of the form of $v=v_0+u$? $u$ is an element of $N(T)$.

I'm currently taking a course of linear algebra in University.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Tv=w$, and suppose that $s$ is a solution of $Tx=w$. Then

$$T(s-v)=Ts-Tv=w-w=0$$

Therefore $s-v$ is in the nullspace of $T$. Hence $s-v=u$, i.e. $s=v+u$, for some $u\in N(T)$.